# Move line until it hits a collection of points

Tags: c#, geometry

I have an imaginary line segment (I have the start and end of the segment) and a `List` of `Point`s. I want to move this line closer to the collection of points until it hits one of them. This image should make things clearer:

[image]

In this image I want to move the green line to the red points until it hits them and get the blue line.

So I have `Point startGreen, endGreen;` and `List<Point> redPoints`. How can I get `Point startBlue, endBlue;`?

Comment: have you tried.....anything?

Comment: @psoshmo Frankly I've worked the whole day and my mind has stopped working hours ago. If you need me to try something before you try to answer, well I can't at the moment.

Comment: I don't think this question should be closed by the current reason, for anyone marked this question as too broad , can you 1. list your "many possible answers" to show how many answers it can be, or 2. post your answer to show how long it would be?

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps:

1. Calculate distance between each point and the green line
2. find minimum distance
3. move green line to the point with minimal distance

-- OR --

1. Find a coordiante transformation which rotates the green line to (say) the y-axis.
2. Transform all points
3. find the point with the largest x-component
4. Move the green line to this point.
5. Do the inverse trsnafomation

Comment: I think the 1st option is better. Easier to implement maybe.

Comment: Do you think you can maybe help me do this?

Comment: @AlirezaNoori you can search this site for ["distance between line and point"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=distance+between+line+and+point).